# An example of an input to the set cover problem which does not provide a 2-approximation

Tags: algorithm, approximation, set-cover

I need some help with the following question:

Show an example of an input to the set cover problem for which **the greedy algorithm shown in class** does not provide a 2-approximation.

**The greedy algorithm:**

**X** - a finite set

**F** - family of subsets of X such that the union gives X

**C** - the desired set of minimal size which covers X.

[image: ctur]

Comment: You can actually find an answer on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm) that presents the greedy algorithm for the set cover problem. It is not yet what you need (it presents a 3/2 approx case), but the idea is here, all you have to do is to adapt it.

Comment: I have figured that example by myself but I still have problem with 2 approx case. Can you give me example for 2 approx case? I stuck this for hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `3/2` approximation example in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm) presenting the greedy algorithm for the set cover problem.
We can see two groups of sets composing `F`. 2 sets (the 'lines'), forming a partition, each of them with half of the 'points'. And 3 other sets (the 'rectangles'), forming another partition, with resp. 2, 4 and 8 points.
The greedy algorithm will choose the 'rectangles' since it starts with the largest set of `F`.
It is possible to adapt this scheme to make a 'worse' approximation, to 'trick' the greedy algorithm.
Recipe: draw the same figure, but with a 31 x 2 grid instead of a 7 x 2. Keep the two lines with half the points in each (still forming a partition), and add two 'rectangles' (the two biggest, they will have resp. 16 and 32 'points') on the right side.
The greedy algorithm will return the 5 'rectangles', while the optimal solution will consist of the two lines, so an approximation of `5/2 > 2`.

Note that this process can be extended infinitly (with a `(2^n)-1 per 2` grid), so you can prove that the greedy algorithm for the set cover is not a `k`-approximaation, for any number `k`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I thought the sets should  be sets like {1,2,3,4}. You gave me another point of view